# I am unabel to console log the last block output? why its happening?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, css-transitions

I have written code to blink blocks recursively and console log the name of the block at the time when I press any key. except for the last key, every block is printing in the console and also I want to run a function that renders a circle in the document with the text in the console and making the buttons disappear while the circle is showing. how can I do this?
(**LMNO is not printing in console**)

```js
let curr_div_on = 0,curr_div_off = 0;


const key = document.getElementsByClassName("key");


function setPlayingOn() {
  key[curr_div_on % 4].classList.add("playing");
  curr_div_on = (curr_div_on + 1) % 4; 
}

function setPlayingOff() {
  key[curr_div_off % 4].classList.remove("playing");
  curr_div_off = (curr_div_off + 1) % 4;
}

setInterval(setPlayingOn, 500);
setTimeout(() => setInterval(setPlayingOff, 500), 500);

document.addEventListener('keypress', function(){
  if(curr_div_on==1){
  console.log('ABCD');
  }else if(curr_div_on==2){
    console.log('EFGH');
  }else if(curr_div_on==3){
    console.log('IJKL');
  }else if(curr_div_on==4){
    console.log('LMNO');
  }
})
```

```css
.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-gap:10px;
  
}

.key{
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  text-align:center;
}

.playing{
  transform: scale(1,1);
    border-color: #ffc600;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1rem #ffc600;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <div class='grid'>
    <button class='key'>ABCD</button>
    <button class='key'>EFGH</button>
    <button class='key'>IJKL</button>
    <button class='key'>LMNO</button>
  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: What error and in what loop?

Comment: you are defining the same id for all div blocks, also, `getElementById` does not return an array of all the blocks that has the same id

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have more than one element with the SAME id, ids must be unique. You can use a class instead.

```js
let curr_div_on = 0,curr_div_off = 0;


const key = document.getElementsByClassName("key");


function setPlayingOn() {
  key[curr_div_on % 4].classList.add("playing");
  curr_div_on = (curr_div_on + 1) % 4; 
}

function setPlayingOff() {
  key[curr_div_off % 4].classList.remove("playing");
  curr_div_off = (curr_div_off + 1) % 4;
}

setInterval(setPlayingOn, 500);
setTimeout(() => setInterval(setPlayingOff, 500), 500);
```

```css
.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-gap:10px;
  
}

.key{
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  text-align:center;
}

.playing{
  transform: scale(1,1);
    border-color: #ffc600;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1rem #ffc600;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <div class='grid'>
    <div class='key'>A</div>
    <div class='key'>B</div>
    <div class='key'>C</div>
    <div class='key'>D</div>
  </div>
</html>
```